# Draw 3D House using Java2D?

Tags: java, graphics, graphics2d

How do I draw a simple 3D house using Java2D? I want to draw the side wall of the house to make it look like a simple 3D drawing.

// House.java

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class House extends Canvas{

  House(){
    setSize(800,600);
  }
  public void paint(Graphics g){

    // house - foundation
    g.setColor(new Color(0xCDBE70));
    g.fillRect(148,500,304,50);

    // house - front
    g.setColor(new Color(0xFFEC8B));
    g.fillRect(150,350,300,150);

    // house - side 
    }    
  }
```

//ShowHouse.java

```
import java.awt.Frame; 
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class ShowHouse extends Frame{ 
  public static void main(String arg[]){
    new ShowHouse(); 
  }
  ShowHouse(){ 
    enableEvents(AWTEvent.WINDOW_EVENT_MASK); 
    setLocation(250,50);
    House canvas = new House();
    add(canvas);
    pack(); 
    setVisible(true);
  }
  public void processWindowEvent(WindowEvent event){
    if(event.getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING) 
      System.exit(0);
  }
  }
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axonometric_projection , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_projection#Perspective_projection

Comment: +1 Thanks. Interesting read. I never knew about the limitations of  objects drawn with axonometric projection do not appear larger or smaller as they extend closer to or away from the viewer.

Comment: Im looking at the isometric projection. I was trying to avoid using general path or drawLine. Instead I was trying to group rectangles and polygons to give it that 3D effect.

Comment: On second though, I might give drawLine a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have rewritten your House Class:

//House.java

```
public class House extends Canvas{

  House(){
    setSize(800,600);
  }
  public void paint(Graphics g){

    Polygon p = new Polygon();
    p.addPoint(100,50);
    p.addPoint(300,50);
    p.addPoint(250,100);
    p.addPoint(50,100);

    g.fillPolygon(p);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setColor(new Color(0xAEAEAE));
    g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(300, 50, 350, 100));
    g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(350, 100, 350, 180));
    g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(350, 180, 250, 180));
    g.setColor(new Color(0xFFEABB));
    p = new Polygon();
    p.addPoint(50,100);
    p.addPoint(250,100);
    p.addPoint(250,180);
    p.addPoint(50,180);

    g.fillPolygon(p);

    g.setColor(new Color(0xFFFFFF));
    p = new Polygon();
    p.addPoint(75,125);
    p.addPoint(225,125);
    p.addPoint(225,150);
    p.addPoint(75,150);

    g.fillPolygon(p);

    }
  }
```